# JavaScriptで数値をカンマ区切りでフォーマットする方法

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

JavaScriptで数値をカンマ区切りする方法としては、
[こちら](http://qiita.com/zawascript/items/922b5db574ef2b126069)の正規表現を使った方法がメジャーなようですが、以下のように

```
var re = /(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g;
String(1234).replace(re, '$1,');      // 1,234 OK
String(1234.56).replace(re, '$1,');   // 1,234.56 OK
String(1234.5678).replace(re, '$1,'); // 1,234.5,678 NG
```

小数点以下が３桁を超えると破綻してしまいます。
どのような解決策があるでしょうか。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

正規表現もいいですけど、 [`Number` の `toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) を使うと楽です。

```
Number(1234).toLocaleString();
-> "1,234"
Number(1234.56).toLocaleString();
-> "1,234.56"
Number(1234.5678).toLocaleString(); 
-> "1,234.568" or '1234.5678'
```

オプションなしだと、小数点が丸められる場合がでてきますが、`IE < 11` を切り捨てられるなら、以下のような形でオプションが付けられます。

```
Number(12345.6789).toLocaleString( undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 20 })
-> "12,345.6789"
Number(12345).toLocaleString('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' })
-> "￥12,345"
Number(1234.56).toLocaleString('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec')
-> "一,二三四.五六"
```

※ mattn のコメントにあるように、 node.js では、カンマは付けられません。これは node.js の V8 が国際化を考慮した [v8-i18n](https://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/) を利用していないためのようです。node.js の場合は[自前でコンパイルするコース](https://github.com/srl295/node/commit/ac2857b12cd819b68405b15c3f8e95e48bcc32d8)かもしれません。

Comment: node.js では動作しませんね。 http://go-gyazo.appspot.com/be922a01b55971a2.png

Comment: おお node.js 環境は考えていませんでした。

Comment: ロケールの設定によっては区切りに使われる文字が異なることにも注意が必要ですね。

Answer (score 4):

正規表現のみでできるのかもしれませんが、
小数点を含む場合は、'.' で分けたほうが手っ取り早いと思います

```
function commafy(n) {
  var parts = n.toString().split('.');
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
  return parts.join('.');
}
```

Comment: splitからのjoinに+1。正規表現は`replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')`の方が若干速いかも。

Answer (score 1):

```
Number.prototype.split3 = function() {
  var r = '', s = this.toString();
  s.match(/(-?)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]*)?/);
  var sp = [RegExp.$1, s = parseInt(RegExp.$2), RegExp.$3];
  while(s >= 1000) {
    r = ',' + (s%1000) + r;
    s = parseInt(s/1000);
  }
  return sp[0] + s + r + sp[2];
}
console.log((1234.5678).split3()); // 1,234.5678
```

整数だけならもう少し速い方法もあります。

http://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/lang/javascript/20071206095908.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
Number.prototype.toCommify = function() {
    return this.toString().replace(/^(-?)(\d+)(?=(\.\d+)?$)/, function() {
        return arguments[1] + arguments[2].replace(/(\d+?)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    });
};
```

整数部と小数部を分けてしまえば。

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /(?:^|[^.])(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g;
String(1234.5678).replace(re, '$1,'); // "1,234.5678"
```

先頭かピリオド以外という条件を加えてはどうでしょうか？